# Google line chart y axis appear 2 times (doubled)

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using google line chart to draw a line chart.If the data used to draw the chart has only one value, as shown in the image, on the vaxis of the chart appear the axis **1** for 2 times and I don't want this.I would like the vaxis to be normal, only with one time axis number.
The code used for vaxis is:

```js
vAxis: 
{
    format: '#',
    minValue: 0,
    gridlines: {
    count: 4
}
```

The chart is: 
[drawn chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTosV.png)

Any response is appreciated

Comment: The type of data shown on the chart is number.:  _cols.Add( new Column { id = "", label = "Downloads", type = "number" } );_

Comment: If I use `vAxis.format: '#,##0.00'` it is almost ok, but the vaxis of the chart will be **0.00 , 0.50 , 1.00 , 1.50** and I don't need **0.50** and **1.50**.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 columns.Those are: `cols.Add( new Column { id = "", label = "Month", type = "string" } );
         cols.Add( new Column { id = "", label = "Downloads", type = "number" } );
         cols.Add( new Column { id = "", role = "annotation", type = "string" } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vAxis.ticks` to an array containing the tick marks needed.
The array could also be built dynamically from the data...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: '', label: 'Month', type: 'string'},
      {id: '', label: 'Downloads', type: 'number'},
      {id: '', role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v: 'February'}, {v: 1}, {v: '1'}]}
    ]
  });

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      format: '#',
      minValue: 0,
      ticks: [0, 1, 2]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, after I had set `vAxis.ticks' it's working. Thank you!